# How to get the groups configured on a publication?

Tags: 2013-sp1, tom.net, user-management

I am using the following code snippet to get the groups configured to a particular publication.

```
var accessRights = publication.AccessControlList.AccessControlEntries;
foreach (var accessRightObj in accessRights)
            {
                 if (!accessRightObj.AllowedRights.Equals("None"))
                 {                    
                    var trustee = accessRightObj.Trustee;
                 }
             }
```

This code works fine but I am also getting the information of the groups configured in the parent publication and inherited by this publication.

How can I simply get the list of groups configured for a publication in TOM.NET?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, does anyone know if we can narrow down the results of user groups using above logic?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are asking. Your code is already getting a list of the access control entries and each Trustee associated with it. A Trustee can either be a user or a group, so I guess you can just check if the Trustee is a Group and if so add it to a list?

Comment: Hi Peter, Yes you are right that I am getting the list of all access control entries but not just for the publication I want for, but also the parent publications which I don't want, so basically want to put a condition or filter to restrict the Trustee Information for a particular publication only.

Hope it is clear now.

Comment: Access control list is not shared from parent publication to child. It defined for each publication separately. However for each publication we create predefined entries for predefined groups like Author, Editor, etc. Are you talking about that groups?

Comment: Hi @StanislavMaryenko,

Yes, you are right that was my understanding too access control list is not shared from parent publication to child but in my case its quite weird apart from the groups like Author,Editor etc. 1 group is continuously coming getting added which is the part of parent publication. The weirdest part is that when I used to call core services in a standalone application, it gives me the exact group information and doesn't include event Author, Editor etc. (FYI I am using TOM.NET in the actual implementation).